# Git merge diff3 style need explanation

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging

I've merged 2 branches and conflicts appeared, I would need some hints where it starts where it ends, etc. I've replaced the code with some faked data to make it easier to read and talk about.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    aaaaaa
||||||| merged common ancestors
<<<<<<< Temporary merge branch 1
    bbbbbb
=======
    cccccc
>>>>>>> mybranch
    dddddd
<<<<<<< HEAD
    eeeeee
||||||| merged common ancestors
    ffffff
||||||| merged common ancestors
    gggggg
=======
>>>>>>> Temporary merge branch 2
=======
    hhhhhh
>>>>>>> mybranch
```

Comment: This diff is weird. Can you show us the original branches? Did the original files contain the merge markers `<<<<<<` ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

What you're seeing in this example (with `Temporary merge branch` markers) is the result of diff3 with a criss-cross merge conflict. I'll explain this with a sequence of definitions.

## Definitions

- **merge base**: The commit where the two merging branches most recently diverged from. When a merge conflict occurs, different changes were made to the same lines in both branches. The *merge base* contains what those lines were before either branch changed them.
- **merged common ancestors**: diff3 outputs an additional "middle" section showing the lines as they were in the *merge base*. This is the starting point for both branches.
- **Criss-cross merge**: A merge history where two branches merge into each other in ways that one could not have been a fast-forward merge. I give an example below. In a criss-cross merge situation, there are multiple *merge bases*.
- **Temporary merge branch**: When there are multiple *merge bases*, diff3 attempts to merge them together (using temporary merge branches) to form a single *common ancestor* to show in diff3's middle section. This works seamlessly when there are no conflicts, but when there are conflicts, you see the temporary merge branch's conflict markers inside the middle *merged common ancestors* section.

## Example criss-cross merge conflict scenario

A criss-cross merge occurs whenever two branches merge into each other at different points in time.

```
m3 *
   |\
   | \
   |  * B1
   |  |
m2 *  * B0
   |\/|
   |/\|
m1 *  * A
   | /
   |/
m0 *
```

Consider this sequence of events:

- `m0` exists as origin/**m**aster
- I create a feature branch `feature-A` with one commit `A`
- `m1` gets committed to master by someone else
- I start a new feature branch `feature-B` that builds on `A`
- I merge `origin/master` (`m1`) into `feature-B`. It conflicts, and I resolve it. The merge commit is `B0`.
- I implement feature-B and commit the work as `B1`.
- `feature-A` is ready to ship, so someone merges it into `master`. It conflicts. They resolve it, but their resolution differs from the resolution in `B0`. The merge commit is `m2`.
- `feature-B` is ready to ship, so someone merges it into `master`. git tries to determine the *merge base*, but `m1` and `A` both qualify equally as merge bases. git merges `m1` and `A` in a *temporary merge branch*, which results in a conflict. We see diff3 output in the *merged common ancestors* section, similar to the OP's question.

## Reading the output

With diff3 off, this merge conflict would look simply like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    aaaaaa
=======
    hhhhhh
>>>>>>> mybranch
```

First, with all the extra markers, you'll want to determine what the actual conflicting lines are, so you can differentiate it from the diff3 common ancestor output.

[image: conflict with merged common ancestor blurred]

aaaaaahhhhhh, that's a little better. ;-)

In the case where two conflict resolutions are conflicting, `aaaaaa` and `hhhhhh` are the two resolutions.

Next, examine the content of the merged common ancestor.

[image: merged common ancestor conflicts, grouped]

With this particular merge history, there were more than 2 merge bases, which required multiple temporary merge branches which were then merged together. The result when there are many merge bases and conflicts can get pretty hairy and difficult to read. Some say don't bother, just turn off diff3 for these situations.

Also be aware that git internally may decide to use different merge strategies to auto-resolve conflicts, so the output can be hard to understand. Make sense out of it if you can, but know that it was not intended for human consumption. In this case, a conflict occurred when merging `mybranch` into `Temporary merge branch 1` between `bbbbbb` and `cccccc`. Line `dddddd` had no conflicts between the temporary merge branches. Then a separate conflict occurred when merging `Temporary merge branch 2` into `HEAD`, with multiple common ancestors. `HEAD` had resolved the conflict by merging `ffffff` and `gggggg` as `eeeeee`, but `Temporary merge branch 2` resolved that same conflict by deleting (or moving) the line (thus no lines between `======` and `Temporary merge branch 2`.

How do you resolve a conflict like this? While technical analysis may be possible, your safest option is usually to go back and review the history in all the involved branches around the conflict, and manually craft a resolution based on your understanding.

## Avoiding all this

These conflicts are the worst, but there are some behaviors that will help prevent them.

1. *Avoid criss-cross merges*. In the example above, `feature-B` merged `origin/master` as `B0`. It's possible that this merge to stay up-to-date with master wasn't necessary (though sometimes it is). If `origin/master` was never merged into `feature-B`, there would have been no merge criss-cross, and `m3` would have been a normal conflict with `A` as the only merge base.

   ```
   m3 *              m3 *
      |\                |\
      | \               | \
      |  * B1           |  * B1
      |  |              |  |
   m2 *  * B0   VS   m2 *  |
      |\/|              |\ |
      |/\|              | \|
   m1 *  * A         m1 *  * A
      | /               | /
      |/                |/
   m0 *              m0 *
   ```
2. *Be consistent with conflict resolutions*. In the example, the *Temporary merge base conflict* only occurred because `m2` and `B0` had different conflict resolutions. If they had resolved the conflict identically, `m3` would have been a clean merge. Realize though that this is a simple criss-cross merge that ought to have had the same resolution. Other situations may rightly have different resolutions. Things get more complicated when there are more than 2 merge bases and multiple commits between the merge points. That said, if you are knowingly inconsistent with conflict resolutions in criss-cross situations, expect headaches later.

Comment: Um, you added the same answer twice?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33419598/456814.

Comment: is the way to fix this, between step 3 and 4, to rebase A off of master? In general I hate merge commits and so I would not have had b0 there, but I am new to this "criss cross merge" so am trying to see whether this criss merge is possible without merge commits.

Comment: @Tommy Correct. If you and your teammates rebase so that your history is linear, then if your history is linear in your scenario, it's not possible to have multiple merge bases and therefore not possible to have a criss-cross merge.

Comment: aaaaaahhhhhh--clever and enlightening--a joy to read.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an article about [git's diff3 merge style](http://psung.blogspot.com/2011/02/reducing-merge-headaches-git-meets.html). It points out that it's hard to tell whether lines are being added or deleted in this style.

I suggest you refine your question if you are looking for specific information. It's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Great link, thanks. I understood the article differently: it's difficult to distinguish additions/deletions in the default conflict style (not shown), but diff3 includes the `|||||||` markers to give context, allowing us to deduce whether a change was an addition or a deletion.