# Where is the official documentation on the set of pipes ("parent of") in git merge conflict markers?

Tags: git

The git docs have [a section which talks about merge conflicts](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#_basic_merge_conflicts) which describes a set of markers added to a file during a merge conflict:

> Git adds standard conflict-resolution markers to the files that have conflicts...

They give you the meanings of `<<<<<<<`, `=======` and `>>>>>>>`, but is there an authoratitive place where *all* the possible markers are defined?

I'm seeing merge conflicts like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
... some code
||||||| parent of cebb63a (my first commit)
... some other code
=======
... a third set of code
>>>>>>> cebb63a (my first commit)
```

The documentation I linked to doesn't mention these pipe symbols (`|||||||`). What are they and where can I find authoratitive documentation on what they mean?

---

#### Update

There's an exhaustive description of the whole issue of conflict-resolution markers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150904/what-is-a-simple-explanation-of-these-git-merge-markers) but this question is a bit more focused on `|||||||` which was unfamiliar to me when I first saw it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a simple explanation of these Git merge markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150904/what-is-a-simple-explanation-of-these-git-merge-markers)

Comment: @CodeCaster it's certainly a great explanation. But it is authoratitive documentation? I usually look for something from `git-scm.com` when looking to understand what git is doing. Is this a dupe? I don't know. I'll let someone better informed in StackOverflow lore/culture than me decide.

Comment: Well the answer is by Torek, which is like a GPT engine tuned to git-scm.com. But yeah there's https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-config#Documentation/merge-config.txt-mergeconflictStyle.

Comment: Apparently Subversion has the same thing. And CVS. (Not that they are ancestors but they came before Git.) So if there isn’t any authoritative Git document about it then I suppose it’s because it was already established practice.

Comment: Your `|||||` comes from the `diff3` style of conflict markers. Meanwhile `====` are from the `merge` style, which was (and is?) the default.

Comment: @CodeCaster The docs you link to in your comment is the answer to this question! Post it as an answer and I'll upvote. I don't think this is quite a duplicate of the other question.